# What else can i use instead new bitmap (Taking too much RAM)

Tags: c#, forms, bitmap

so i got this program that i built. there's some of the code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            image1 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = image1;
        }
    }
```

now every time that i change the picture with the button the ram usage is increased.
a friend of mine told me that's happened because i'm assign new memory space every time i'm doing this :

```
new Bitmap(openDialog.Filename);
```

what's the solution for this?
(i tried to search in google but i didnt really know what to search for that..)

EDIT :

now its working thanks for help. 
edited code for others :

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
     if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
         pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

        image1 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = image1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you arent disposing of the old image, so your app is leaking

Comment: how can i disposing the old image?

Comment: `if(pictureBox1.Image!=null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose()` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Image. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Image object's Finalize method.

As the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.dispose(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation says, you  must call `Dispose`. If you want to extract something from image and then dispose, it's better to use the `Using` keyword; *e.g.*:

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmapLocation)){
    // extract data from bitmap
}
```

After execution leaves the `using` braces, the bitmap's `Dispose` method will be called and the object will be disposed.